# mySQL 5.5.23 will not start on OSX 10.7.3

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

I originally installed mySQL on OSX and it started fine.  I was able to connect with mySQL workbench and create a database.  However, after a reboot mySQL will no longer start.

The launch fails with the following message taken from the error log:

[ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'

Also checked the activity monitor and there is no other mySQL process running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the ../etc/my.cnf file allowed the server to start successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an upgrade has incremented your versions, because on my systems running 5.0.x the `mysqld` supports `--skip-locking`, but by 5.5 it is gone....

```
# /usr/libexec/mysqld --verbose --help | grep skip-lock
  --skip-locking      Deprecated option, use --skip-external-locking instead.

[root@g0801 ~]# rpm -q mysql-server
mysql-server-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1
```

Now  it is gone, from the 5.5 binary options....

```
$ rpm -q mysql-server
 mysql-server-5.5.22-1.fc16.x86_64

 $ /usr/libexec/mysqld --verbose --help 
 No such option --skip-locking
```

Comment: I installed mySQL 5.5.23 on OSX and there was no other version of mySQL out there at the time.  Now I did add mySQL as a server within Eclipse and selected the option to "Use Tomcat Installation".  It appears to start correctly within Eclipse so I'm wondering if it changed one of the config files?

Comment: sounds plausible, if there is nothing in the services script, then to check whether any of the service control options got carried over. I am not familiar with Max OS x, but it seems have a "services control menu" which might have those legacy options enabled.

Comment: I was unsuccessful in getting this to run. Any suggestions for what I might check?  I did try re-installing (without running an uninstall) and that did not resolve the issue.